# Will there be new Xcode releases for new iOS 10 betas?

Tags: ios, xcode, beta, ios10

I got an Xcode beta that supports compiling to iOS 10 Beta 1.

If Beta 2/public beta will be released, will there be a new Xcode beta release?

And will my code written for iOS 9 will work the same (except NSLog) on iOS 10?

Comment: @Rob So that means, I don't need the new xCode betas

Comment: @Rob I accept that as a correct answer. Please post this answer **not as a comment** as soon as possible.

Comment: Why are people downvoting this? I could not find any data about that on the official XCode website of Apple. And I wrote a short question, because I wanted a short answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time a new beta is released, it's generally accompanied with a new Xcode beta release. So if you're programming against a beta OS, not only update your device with the latest OS but always plan on installing the latest Xcode beta, too.

Regarding whether code written for iOS 9 will work on iOS 10, if you have existing iOS 9 apps out on the store, they will generally work fine with iOS 10. But when you go to recompile your old iOS 9 code with iOS 10 (e.g. you're planning on issuing a new release of your app), you may have to change your code to compile correctly.

Xcode 8 includes both Swift 2.3 (for which there will only be a few changes you'll likely have to make) and Swift 3.0 (requiring even more changes). Xcode 8 has conversion tools to help automate the conversion from Swift 2.2 to 2.3 or 3.0, respectively. Needless to say, before converting your code from Swift 2.2 to 2.3/3.0, keep a back copy of your old Swift 2.2 code, because you don't want to lose 2.2 code, because you can't use 2.3/3.0 in production apps until iOS 10 is no longer beta software.